# Angular get the index value of item in an object

Tags: angular, typescript

With a simple HttpClient:

```
this.getService.getAPI(this.profileUrl).subscribe(
    data => {
        this.profile = data;
    }
);
```

I get a JSON object that looks like the following:

```
{
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe",
    "frequency": "w",
    "frequency_name": "Weekly",
    "delivery": "e",
    "delivery_name": "Evening",
    "timezone_offset": "America/Los Angeles"
}
```

so I know that something like `{{ profile.first_name }}` will return John as a value, but in the particular instance I am working on I actually need to get the value of the key itself. How would I do this?

Comment: The value of the key? Which key? And if you know the key, you know it, so you don't need the object to know it. What exactly do you want to do? List the keys of the object?

Comment: right so in a later function I am making a put request and I need to "put" for example `frequency: w` when the appropriate button is clicked. so to make this dynamic i need to pass the index name and the new value to my method. so that is why i need the index name.

Comment: `console.log(this.profile.keys());` tells me `ERROR TypeError: _this.profile.keys is not a function` am i doing this wrong?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

You could create a pipe to manipulate the Key-Value pairs of your object:

```
interface KeyValuePair {
  key: string;
  value: any;
}

@Pipe({
  name: 'keyValuePairs'
})
export class KeyValuePairsPipe implements PipeTransform{
   transform(value: Object): KeyValuePair[]{
     let result: KeyValuePair[] = []; 
     if(!!value && value instanceof Object){
        result = Object.entries(value).map(pair => ({ key: pair[0], value: pair[1] }))
     }
     return result;
   }
}
```